# Mojolicious session expires versus default_expiration

Tags: perl, session, timeout, mojolicious

I have a program where I want the session data to expire at an absolute Epoch time after a  request.  I don't want the expiration to update for every request.

default_expiration works but not expires.

This does not work:

```
post '/access' => sub {
    my $self = shift;
    my $user = $self->param('username');
    if ($self->authenticate($user, $self->param('password'))) {

        ### Set this otherwise timeout refreshes for every request...
        $self->session(expires => time + 120);
        (...)
    }
};
```

Mojolicious cookie set to 1 hour (3600s) the default...

$self->sessions->default_expiration(120) works but reset for every browser request.

I am using the Mojolicious::Plugin::Authentication plugin.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`expiration`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojolicious%3a%3aSessions#default_expiration) key to set the same value as the default_expiration does. Before you set the value though, be sure to check to see if the key exists already and don't overwrite it if it does.